How to upload all folders, subfolders and files from file explorer to SharePoint library using PowerAutomate?
How to upload all folders, subfolders and files from file explorer to SharePoint library using PowerAutomate?
How i can upload all folders, subfolders and files from file explorer to SharePoint library using PowerAutomate? I am able to get files in a folder but dont know how i can traverse each subfolder and look for a file till last.

Have a look at desktop flows and RPA features:

Desktop flows broaden the existing robotic process automation (RPA)
capabilities in Power Automate and enable you to automate all
repetitive desktop processes. Automating is quicker and easier than
ever with the new intuitive Power Automate desktop flow designer using
the prebuilt drag-and-drop actions or recording your own desktop flows
to run later.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/introduction
But easier (and cheaper) might be other solutions:

OneDrive Sync Client:

You can use the OneDrive sync client to sync your SharePoint document library to your local machine. Any files, folders, or subfolders that you copy to the synced folder on your desktop will automatically upload to the corresponding location in SharePoint.
Pros: Easy setup, real-time sync, no scripting required.
Cons: Limited to OneDrive/SharePoint and relies on the local sync process.

SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT)?

PowerShell Script with PnP PowerShell?
Copy-PnPFile [-SourceUrl]  [-TargetUrl]  [-Overwrite] [-Force] [-IgnoreVersionHistory] [-NoWait] [-Connection ]



I tried one drive for business to sync folders with SharePoint library. But my question is, will that be taking up space in server's hard drive as the location of organization folder created after sync is showing as C drive only?

What do you mean by server's hard drive? SharePoint Online storage space? Yes, the documents will count towards the SharePoint and OneDrive limits.
Local hard drive? It depends on the sync options. You can choose which folders to sync https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-which-onedrive-folders-to-sync-to-your-computer-98b8b011-8b94-419b-aa95-a14ff2415e85   or where should the copy be stored AFTER SYNC: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-mark-onedrive-files-or-folders-as-always/feaa9be2-2d5a-43aa-b7e4-b8f62fea9fbd

I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved.
